# Put headphones - Ubuntu gets in speaker mode / No headphones - Ubuntu gets in headphones mode

Tags: headphones

It's the exact opposite with my laptop, speakers setting → headphones mode and headphones → speakers. Does anyone have an idea why?

Comment: It could be a prank. Check which port the speaker cable is plugged into.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'm the only one using the laptop so I don't think it's a prank, how do you check the ports?

Comment: The ports where the audio out and mic cables get plugged in usually have little symbols stamped into the sheet metal or molded into the plastic that you can see in a strong light if you look carefully. These little symbols are like icons that tell what each port is for.

Comment: Thank you, I only have one entrance for both micro and headphones, I know it recognizes them because it changes between them, but it is exactly the opposite, it is so weird, if i put headphones I get sound from speakers, if I put speakers only sound for headphones (useless unless Bluetooth or the one second before he recognizes i out headphones)